# Android Apps using python

Tags: java, android, python, eclipse, sdk

I found that Android development can be done through Python from the link http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7157/1. My question is whether all the libraries that are available in Java are also available in python.

Any of you already started with python on Android if so please indicate links to help get our group up to speed.

Answer (score 1):

No, not all the libraries have been exposed. You can look at the [SL4A project on google-code](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) for more information regarding the support it has.

> **Is this a complete API bridge, or are there restrictions?**
>   BeanShell, JRuby, and Rhino basically give you a complete API bridge (you can invoke Java calls directly). See the documentation for those interpreters for instruction on how to accomplish this. Cross compiled languages like Lua are more restricted. They only have access to the APIs exposed through the RPC layer. See the API reference for a list of currently supported APIs. The RPC layer is easy to extend.